# How to control the number of threads/cores used?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running Spark on a local machine, with 8 cores, and I understand that I can use "local[num_threads]" as the master, and use "num_threads" in the bracket to specify the number of threads used by Spark.

However, it seems that Spark often uses more threads than I required. For example, if I only specify 1 thread for Spark, by using the top command on Linux, I can still observe that the cpu usage is often more than 100% and even 200%, implying that more than 1 threads are actually used by Spark.

This may be a problem if I need to run multiple programs concurrently. How can I control the number of threads/cores used strictly by Spark?

Comment: That's not the number of threads. That's the number of concurrent tasks that Spark will execute (a task being part of an action on an RDD). Spark uses several other threads for different things such as handling communication and service the driver's UI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Then is there a way to control the number of cores/processors used by Spark?

Comment: Not in the way you want. You can control the number of concurrent tasks, but that's it. If you want more, you'll have to use some OS-level control such as Linux cgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses one thread for its scheduler, which explains the usage pattern you see it. If you launch `n` threads in parallel, you'll get `n+1` cores used.

For details, see the [scheduling doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application).

Comment: Hi, I am getting same problem of high cpu usages , can you tell me how to limit the cpu usages by spark.